# Arbitrary PEMDAS

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

Scrolling through social media, one might encounter something like this:

[image: Very easy expression to simplify]

We can see that, following PEMDAS order of operations, the answer is clearly <strike>1</strike><sup>*1*</sup> 9.

For the sake of this challenge, PEMDAS means that multiplication will occur before division, so `a/b*c = a/(b*c)`, not `(a/b)*c`. The same goes for addition and subtraction. For example, using PEMDAS, `1-2+3 = -4`, but using PEMDSA, `1-2+3 = 2`.

However, the answer quickly changes if we use some other order of operations, say PAMDES: now the answer is 1<sup>*2*</sup>.

#### The challenge

Given an expression and an order of operations, output the value it equals.

#### Input

The input will contain two parts: the expression and the order of operations.

The expression will contain only `[0-9] ( ) ^ * / + -`. This means that it will contain only integers; however, you may not use integer division, so `4/3=1.33` (round to *at least* two decimal places), not `1`.

The order of operations may be taken in any reasonable format. For example, you may take a string array of operations (ex. `["()", "^", ... ]`), or something like `PEMDAS`. Parenthesis will always have the highest priority, and will therefore always come first in the input.

#### Output

The inputted expression evaluated and rounded to at least two decimal places.

#### This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

#### Test cases

```
PEMDAS 4*3-2+1             =  9
PDEMAS 2*4^3+2             =  130
PMDASE 17^2-1*2            =  1
PSEMAD 32*14/15-12+5^3+1/2 =  1.736
PEMDAS 6/2*(1+2)            =  1
PEDMAS 6/2*(1+2)            =  9
PDMSEA 2*(1*13+4)^3        =  39304
```

<sub>1. No joke: many thought the answer was 1.</sub>

<sup>2. Here we are using the "for the sake of this challenge" PEMDAS rules.</sup>

Comment: Will concatenation ever be used to indicate multiplication, or will there be an explicit `*` every time? (Note that this is precisely the issue that caused people to think that the answer to the original puzzle is 9, even though it really is 1: concatenation-notated multiplication has a higher precedence than division in practice.)

Comment: @GregMartin, no, there will never be any concatenation

Comment: Can the output be left as an exact fraction, rather than rounded off as a decimal?

Comment: @GregMartin, it doesn't have to be rounded

Comment: Another question! Can we take the expression in with spaces surrounding operators, like `17 ^ 2 - 1 * 2` instead of `17^2-1*2`?

Comment: @GregMartin, any reasonable input works.

Comment: I cannot understand for the life of me how the answer to the top equation is 9 if multiplication comes before division. Maybe I'll read the challenge again when I'm not so tired and understand it....

Comment: @ETHproductions, the answer is 9 under normal PEMDAS, where for * and / it is whichever comes first from left to right (same for + and -). Normally, * and / have equal precedence. However, in this challenge, the precedence is decreasing from left to right in the acronym/input.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61463/21348 related or duplicate?

Comment: It's a duplicate, I can simply post my old answer to that challenge and it correctly answer this one

Comment: @Dopapp, Oh, I see now, thanks for the explanation. I guess I was wrong in thinking that multiplication by juxtaposition came before regular muliplication and division.

Comment: @ETHproductions: when kids are taught PEMDAS, they're taught that multiplication and division have the same predecence and should be evaluated left to right. However, as a practicing mathematician, I can report that this is oversimplistic: in practice, multiplication-by-juxtaposition does have higher precedence than division. Expressions like `1/3x` and `a/b(c-d)` are never interpreted as `(1/3)x` or `(a/b)(c-d)`. The `÷` symbol is not often used outside of school math, but even then, no practicing mathematician would look at `6÷2(1+2)` and interpret it as `(6÷2)(1+2)`.

Comment: @GregMartin Hmm, that's what I originally thought. So the example given is just a "following the letter of the law" kind of thing.... That makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @ETHproductions, originally I was going to write "follow the letters to the letter", but that sounded confusing when I said it out loud.

Comment: This reminds me of yesterday when I was writing an arithmetic-calculating function and struggling to get the order of operations right... At one point, `1+0!*7**2` would give 50, but `1+0!*(7**2)` would give 98. It took me forever to figure out why :P (I don't remember the reason, but it had something to do with `1+0!` being calculated first in the latter case)

Answer (score 1):

## Maxima, <s>61</s> 67 bytes

```
f(O,E):=(for i:1 thru 5 do infix(O[7-i],i*20,i*20),eval_string(E));
```

A function that takes operators as a list of strings and the expression and returns the result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/maxima#@5@m4a/jqmllq5GWX6SQaWWoUJJRVKpgqpCSr5CZl5ZZoeEfba6bGauTqWVkACY0dVLLEnPii0uKMvPSNVw1Na3/cxUA2SUaaRrRShqaSjpK@kCsBcS6QBwHxNpKsTpKRloahlqGxtommnHGSkBdXP8B)

Example:

```
f(["()","^","*","/","+","-"],"4*3-2+1");
```

result: `9`

Comment: That seems to have trouble with parens

Comment: @ChristianSievers Thanks, answer updated.